# Rails flash hash being rendered one request too soon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue in Rails 3 where the flash hash seems to be returning things one request too early. That is, it seems to return things upon rendering that were set in that very same request. For example, consider a controller action that does:

```
    add_warning "Danger, will robinson."
```

In my ApplicationController, I have:

```
    before_filter :set_errors
    #...
    def set_errors
      flash[:errors] ||= []
      flash[:warnings] ||= []
      flash[:notices] ||= []
    end
    #...
    def add_warning(msg)
      flash[:warnings] << msg
    end
```

And my application.html.erb layout template has

```
    <% flash[:warnings].each do |msg| %>
      <div class="warnings"><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Based on what I'm understanding from the Rails guide, the flash contents shouldn't be rendered in this same request unless I'm using flash.now. And, if I have a redirect_to, they SHOULD be rendered in that second request. But they don't show up at all when the redirect_to happens.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to reinvent the wheel.  If you use flash like it's supposed to be used (as a session store) then it works like it should.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: That's exactly how I want to use it, except that I want support for an arbitrary number of multiple error messages. Because that example only assigns a string, it only supports a single error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason for the issue was the set_errors method, combined with my lack of understanding of how the flash hash works.

It seems that if a new value is not assigned to a key in flash, then the value of that key will be nil on the NEXT request. This may seem obvious, but the implications are subtle because I was assigning values to keys with ||= ("or-equals") on each request.

Consider the case where I have a series of requests to the same action, which don't ever call add_warning:

On the first request, flash is an empty hash. It contains no keys, so the ||= assigns some.

On the second request, flash is a hash with three keys, each value an empty array. Now, since each key has a value, the ||= does not assign anything. Which means that on the third request, rails has cleared those values and flash is an empty hash once again.

Now, consider this case:

On the first request, flash in an empty hash. It contains no keys, so the ||= assigns some.

On the second request, flash is a hash with three keys, each value an empty array. Now, an action calls add_error. However, **an array already exists at flash[:warnings]**. So, a value is pushed into that array. The contents of the array have changed, **but the value of flash[:warnings] has not changed - it is still a reference to the same array**. Hence, two implications:

1. The value of flash[:warnings] (i.e., the reference to an array) has not changed during this action, so because we've **modified** the same object that rails assigned to flash[:warnings] at the beginning of the request, it gets rendered with the newly pushed message at render time.
2. The value of flash[:warnings] (i.e., the reference to an array) has not changed during this action, so the action prompted by the next request will not have a :warnings key in flash at all.

So, in conclusion, the subtle point is that **assigning a new value** to a key in the flash hash is what causes it to be available in the **following** request.

EDIT: I guess it might help to post my solution, which is to eliminate the set_error and before_filter entirely, and instead to put the ||= [] fragment in the add_error method. That way, values are assigned to the flash hash only when they should be - when an error message is added.

Answer (score 0):

`flash` and `flash.now` both render, but `flash.now` does so immediately, while plain old `flash` only renders after you redirect.

http://blog.vedanova.com/2010/09/29/rails-flash-now/

Based on your main question, it sounds like you want to use `flash` instead of `flash.now`

Comment: No, I don't want to reset the arrays to nil, because you can't push a string to nil and have it magically become an array.

Comment: ok i'll update to keep it initializing empty arrays. What is your reason for using the ||= on them? If there's something in it already it wont reset them to empty.

Comment: No; as you can see from my example, I was never using flash.new.

Comment: @fearpi Ease up on your tone.  jstim is just trying to help.

Comment: what action are you calling that's causing the flash to render too early? Can we see that method? I am wondering if you are running into an issue with the :before_filter. Just a guess

Answer (score 0):

`flash.now` need when you can't lost `params[]` for example: user filling the form for new post and have mistake in title for example (action *new* in **Posts** controller), he push submit and data send to *create* action, we have `params[:post][:title]` but if it's not valid and after we redirect to *new* action we already haven't `params[:post][:title]` and we can't fill field and user lost all filled data and user will be angry =) In this case, we use `render` and we still need to show warning, we use `flash.now`.

In other way we use just `flash[]` *new action* **(1)->** *create action* (we set `flash[]` var) **(2)->** *index action* we show `flash[]`. Like params in 1st example we lost `flash[]` after 2nd step.

Sorry for my pretty bad English, especially in long text.

Comment: As I indicated in comments to jstim's answer, I wasn't using flash.now.